# How functions in the controller are chosen?

Tags: php, laravel-4, restful-url

I have seen the below functionality and I don't understand how functions in controller is choosed?

```
class ProfilesController extends \BaseController {

  public function index() {}

  public function create() {}

  public function store(){}

  public function show($id){}

  public function edit($id){}

  public function update($id){}

  public function destroy($id){}

   }
```

For *local.com/profiles* it would call `index()` function and list all the profiles. For viewing any record *local.com/profiles/99* it is using `show()` method.
For editing any record *local.com/profiles/99/edit* it is using `edit()`.

Are these methods are created automatically? Please suggest me any link or document which helps in understanding `Laravel` better.

Comment: I don't know the exact answer but it must be something with REST and POST/GET/PUT/DELETE http request methods.

Comment: Here be your answer http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: @cen: is there any document you can refer me to read?.

Comment: afarazit pretty much answered it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The links provided to you are good to understand how to implement restful urls in `Laravel` but you don't know what is *restful*.

The method naming chosen by `Laravel` it's a convention used to represent what each method does. It's called [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete).

Now which method is been called depends on the [HTTP Request Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete).

```
GET     /resource                   index   resource.index
GET     /resource/create            create  resource.create
POST    /resource                   store   resource.store
GET     /resource/{resource}        show    resource.show
GET     /resource/{resource}/edit   edit    resource.edit
PUT/PATCH   /resource/{resource}    update  resource.update
DELETE     /resource/{resource}     destroy resource.destroy
```

To avoid redundant code when we have a `CRUD` we use [resource controller](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers).

You have to add the below route to your *routes.php* and the controller you have already provide.

```
Route::resource('profile', 'ProfilesController');
```

It's the same as writing

```
Route::get('profile', 'ProfilesController@index'));
Route::get('profile/create', 'ProfilesController@create'));
Route::post('profile', 'ProfilesController@store'));
Route::get('profile/{id}', 'ProfilesController@show'));
Route::get('profile/{id}/edit', 'ProfilesController@edit'));
Route::put('profile/{id}', 'ProfilesController@update'));
Route::patch('profile/{id}', 'ProfilesController@update'));
Route::delete('profile/{id}', 'ProfilesController@destroy'));
```

If you want to generate those lines. You can use Jeffreys Way [generators.](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators#resources)

See [Teach a Dog to REST](http://vimeo.com/17785736) to understand what I'm talking about.

Comment: Could also be noted that if you want to see a summary of your routes, their controller and function which handles it, you can type `php artisan routes`.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at github Laravel page at Router.php -> 
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php

Check the resourceDefaults and addResource* functions :)

--
And of course go to Laravel documentation > http://laravel.com/docs/controllers there is the info which you need for your work..

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Resource Controllers, http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers.